# Получение данных для Android приложения?

Tags: java, android

Всем привет! У меня возник вопрос, где обычно хранят и как  нужно получать данные для андройд приложения. Начнем с приложения которое работает с подключением в интернет. Допустим есть какой то сервис по машинам типо http://kolesa.kz/. Было разработано Андройд приложение. Как пользователь может получиться данные с сайта для приложения! Есть две догадки.

Какой то php файл принимает запрос от Андройд приложения, генерит xml. И возвращает приложению. Приложение его парсит и выводит пользователю.

Второй вариант: Как то php файл принимает запрос от приложения, возвращает json Данные, приложение коннектится и получает эти данные.

Расскажите как вы считаете правильным получать данные удаленно?

p.s. Если кто то подробно расскажет в скайпе как выглядит структура (готовый код не нужен) закину 200 рублей на счет.

Comment: вы забыли еще, что можно просто тупо парсить сайты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути не важно что возвращает сервер - XML или JSON, андроид может распарсить и то и то. В последнее время более популярен JSON.
Парсить сайт это очень большой геморрой и при малейших изменения на сайте клиент перестанет работать.

Answer (score 0):

В случае php-файлов - необходимо иметь доступ к сайту, чтобы самому формировать данные, которые необходимо получать при определенном запросе. Некоторые сайты имеют API для этих целей. Как вариант можно использовать библиотеку [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/), она может парсить HTML, но тут будут сложности с получением данных которые в данный момент не отображаются, например записей, которые хранятся в базе данных

Answer (score 0):

Та же ситуация была. Первый вариант JSOUP, второй - писать письма в поддержку сайта для получения доступа к их RESTAPI, если таково имеется, но это не со всеми прокатит. Если у вас контора без имени или вас просто никто не знает -  конечно не дадут доступ.

Но есть одно большое НО! Если вы будете использовать JSOUP в приложении с большим количеством запросов на сайт, то можно лихо получить по шапке, т.к. можно положить их сервера. Так что, в таком варианте на свой страх и риск.
Я сначала рассылал письма. Многие предоставили API, некоторые отказались, другие молчали - тут уже jsoup вступил ;)